# Why does my modal box pop up with a message that says invalid object passed in when I try populate it with data based on what I have clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, modal-dialog

Why does my modal box pop up with a message that says invalid object passed in when I try populate it with data based on what I have clicked

I have a table that has some customer data within it so when I click on a customer I want a popup that displays the rest of that customers details but 
the pop up displays a message saying invalid object passed in. Please note that the method client populates the data and the is shown via a partial view. My link to load the popup is at called View

**here is my code below**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "View Details"
        });
        $("#tableData .details").click(function () {
            //var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            //var InfoId = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FilteredSearch/Client",
                data: '{Id: "' + id + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //dataType: "html",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#dialog').html(response);
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });




 <table id="tableData" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>

            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Cell1
            </th>

            <th>
                Email1
            </th>

            <th>
                Identification Number
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Export", "ExportSearchDataToExcel", new { conditionBasedSearch = condition })
                @*<button onclick="exportToExcel()">
                        Export to Excel
                    </button>*@
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td><a class="details"  href="javascript:;" data-id = @item.ClientId>View</a></td>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cell1)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdentificationNumber)
            </td>


            @*<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientDataId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ClientDataId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClientDataId })
        </td>*@
        </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: It looks like you are giving the `html()` method an object, resulting from a json response.  That seems weird, just at a passing glance.

Comment: yes I thought that might be an issue. How can I change that what is the correct way

Comment: Plus your `id` is not what you expect it to be unless you want it to have the value of `"View"`.

Comment: so should id be data-id instead?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I would advise something like the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "View Details"
  });
  $("#tableData").on("click", ".details", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/FilteredSearch/Client",
      data: { id: id },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#dialog").html("");
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
          $("#dialog").append("<label>" + key + ":</label>" + value + "<br />");
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<table id="tableData" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Cell1</th>
    <th>Email1</th>
    <th>Identification Number</th>
    <th><button onclick="exportToExcel()">Export to Excel</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="details" data-id="1002">View</a></td>
    <td>Homer</td>
    <td>Simpson</td>
    <td>417-555-1212</td>
    <td>hsimpson@springfieldpowerplant.com</td>
    <td>1002</td>
    <td>Edit | Details | Delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks this got me a step forward only problem is that I am getting an error that says Invalid JSON primitive: id.

Comment: @Zidane maybe need to to stringify your payload? `data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),`